# Create non-looping Polylines in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got an array of Coordinates for which I want to create PolyLines in the Maps API v3. I've done the following so far.

```
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  //locations is an array of Lat, Long
        var a = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
        plans.push(a)
        bounds.extend(a);
    }

    var roadPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: plans,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    roadPath.setMap(map);
```

Now the problem here is, on creating the polylines, the last and first point get connected too as illustrated

[image: PolyLine]

where the leftmost point is the first point and the rightmost is the last coordinate in the array `locations`. How do I make the red line stick only to the road and not as the crow flies?

Comment: The API doesn't connect the points, when they are connected you've duplicated the first or last point.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `pushing all` the points at the same time `pass pair` of points then your problem will be solved.i.e. try to draw path using `pair of points`.like: for first time `send origin and first` point,then `second pair is first point and second point` so on.

**e.g.**:supoose you have array of points as:`origin,first,seond,third,......,last,destination`.then send `origin,first` as `first pair` then `first,second` as `second pair`,`second and third` as `third pair` ,.....,`last,destination` as `last pair` to google direction services or polyline.

here make sure that origin and destination are not same if they are same then do not send last pair.

Comment: i have explained in example.

Comment: This post ended up in low quality queue. I voted against, but it's easy to understand why. @SuchitKumar, you `need` to stop `misusing inline` formatting to highlight `parts of your` posts - I checked your other answers, you do it often. Please use other formatting options, e.g. \*\*bold\*\* or \_italic\_. This irritates people and makes your post harder, not easier, to read.

Answer (score 0):

This probably due to: 
1. Duplicated sets of data. You may have pushed two or more sets of data into your polyline path, so when one ends, it is connected to the original coordinate and forming the loop.
2. You added your original coordinate to the end of your buffer.